# Can't execute "Hello world" on Raspberry Pi 3B with OpenWrt

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, openwrt

I am trying to compile Helloworld for Raspberry Pi 3B with openwrt.

Helloworld.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hell! O' world, why won't my code compile?\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
# build helloworld executable when user executes "make"
helloworld: helloworld.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) helloworld.o -o helloworld
helloworld.o: helloworld.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c helloworld.c

# remove object files and executable when user executes "make clean"
clean:
    rm *.o helloworld
```

I upload to raspberry via ssh and. When i execute helloworld I get this response

```
root@LEDE:~# ./helloworld 
./helloworld: line 1: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")
```

When I am using this guide https://manoftoday.wordpress.com/2007/10/11/writing-and-compiling-a-simple-program-for-openwrt/ I get this after using makefile

```
user@debian:~/OpenWrt-SDK-Linux-i686-1$ make V=99
make package/compile
make[1]: Entering directory «/home/user/OpenWrt-SDK-Linux-i686-1»
Collecting package info...
make -C package compile SDK=1
make[2]: Entering directory «/home/user/OpenWrt-SDK-Linux-i686-1/package»
Makefile:3: /home/user/OpenWrt-SDK-Linux-i686-1/.pkgdeps: No such file or directory
/home/user/OpenWrt-SDK-Linux-i686-1/include/host.mk:8: /home/user/OpenWrt-SDK-Linux-i686-1/tmp/.host.mk: No such file or directory
--: /home/user/OpenWrt-SDK-Linux-i686-1/include/shell.sh;: No such file or directory
--: /home/user/OpenWrt-SDK-Linux-i686-1/include/shell.sh;: No such file or directory
/home/user/OpenWrt-SDK-Linux-i686-1/include/host.mk:13: failed to perform the recipe for the target «/home/user/OpenWrt-SDK-Linux-i686-1/tmp/.host.mk»
make[2]: *** [/home/user/OpenWrt-SDK-Linux-i686-1/tmp/.host.mk] Error 1
make[2]: Exit from directory «/home/user/OpenWrt-SDK-Linux-i686-1/package»
Makefile:48: failed to perform the recipe for the target «package/compile»
make[1]: *** [package/compile] Error 2
make[1]: Exit from directory «/home/user/OpenWrt-SDK-Linux-i686-1»
Makefile:54: failed to perform the recipe for the target «world»
make: *** [world] Error 2
```

What I did wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: First, try `make helloworld`.  Second, when I copied your makefile I noticed you had spaces where there should be tabs.  That might be a feature of "copy and paste", but ensure that the indented lines in front of `$(CC)` and `rm` are a single tab, NOT spaces.

Comment: Using  make helloworld didn't help me. It's feature of "copy and paste". I am using tabs.

Comment: What happened?  Did you change the spaces to a tab?

Comment: When i try "make helloworld" it's compile well and i can execute program on computer, but if i execute it on raspberry i get response like that root@LEDE:~# ./helloworld 
./helloworld: line 1: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")

Comment: There is no lines which started with spaces, only tabs. It's feature of "copy and paste"

Comment: Ah, are you compiling on a different machine then?

Comment: Yes, I am compiling programm on PC and then I upload binary file on Raspberry and execute it on raspberry.

Answer (score 0):

arm and x86 problem?
Listen to me, install make and gcc into Openwrt using 'opkg install make gcc'
And then build yout project on Openwrt, it well done.
Where is your problem come from? it's caused by platform difference.
So if your always want to build it on x86 platform, using cross compiler please.